# MonoTouch DateTime.ToLocalTime does not update when time zone is changed

Tags: ios, datetime, xamarin.ios

When I change the time zone on my computer (when testing on the simulator) or on the phone (when testing directly on the phone), `DateTime.ToLocalTime()` does not return updated results.

I register and successfully receive notification events for `UIApplication.Notifications.ObserveSignificantTimeChange`. In it I call `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()` which allows me to detect the time zone has in fact changed but this has no effect on `ToLocalTime()`. The `DateTime` I am converting is definitely of kind Utc (tried `DateTime.UtcNow` for example).

I tried calling `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData()` as suggested in this question: [SetTimeZoneInformation does not update DateTime.Now for another .NET Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137383/settimezoneinformation-does-not-update-datetime-now-for-another-net-application). That only causes the application to crash when the `CurrentCulture` is nulled.

Digging a bit deeper into the implementation of `ToLocalTime()`, it seems to use the object `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone`. This object is reset only when the difference between `DateTime.GetNow()` and `TimeZone.timezone_check`. I suspect that `TimeZone.timezone_check` is not getting updated when `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()` is called.

Is there any way I can force `ToLocalTime()` to take into consideration the time zone change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DateTimeOffset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264617/when-would-you-prefer-datetime-over-datetimeoffset) for this. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331189/datetime-vs-datetimeoffset).

*Edit* - What I have working is this:

```
var dateTimeUtc = new System.DateTime(2013, 2, 4, 21, 30, 0, 
                                        System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
var dateTimeOffsetLocal = new System.DateTimeOffset(dateTimeUtc.ToLocalTime());
var formattedLocalTime = string.Format("{0:HH:mm}", dateTimeOffsetLocal);
```

On my phone my `formattedLocalTime` changes whenever I change my `TimeZone` on it, without clearing any cache. I do have to reload the view, but no other tricks.

To display/verify the local `TimeZone` I use:

```
var localTimeZone = System.TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName;
```

I hope this somehow points you in the right direction. I don't have any better than this "works on my machine(s)"-anwer.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I run into the same problem. Calling `DateTimeOffset.ToLocalTime()` still makes use of `TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone` which does not seem to get updated.

Comment: I'll have to look into my own implementation. This one is working for me. Hoop to get back on this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I feel like I'm missing something. I tried `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(myUTCDate, TimeZoneInfo.Local)` which uses an up to date TimeZoneInfo, but I am still getting the wrong local time when I print out the result.

Comment: I expanded my answer with a sample from my own code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jacco, I am still looking deeper into this, I'm pretty sure there's a bug on my side. Just to be clear, this works for you on the iOS simulator?